# How do i add a cookie to my popup form? Built only with css and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

**strong text**I have a popup form that shows up onpage load... but i have only used html and css for this...

I want to be able to add a cookie that makes the popup only show once onpage load how can i do this?

Also how can i put a delay on the form so it doesnt pop up instantly.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/popupForm.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
    #popup {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isfirst = localStorage.getItem('status');
        if (isfirst == null) {
            localStorage.setItem('status', 1);
            // SHow popup here
            $('#popup').show();
        }
    });

</script>
```

```
<div class="popup-wrapper" id="popup">
    <div class="popup-container">
        <!-- Popup Contents, just modify with your own -->
        <form id="popupForm" class="form-style1" method="post" action="http://robust.flg360.co.uk/api/APIHTTPPost.php">
            <div class="formLogo"></div>
            <h2>Enquire Now for a Free Information Pack</h2>
            <div class="columns six">
                <p>
                    This form is simply here to speed up the process enter your details and one of our friendly & professional
                    course advisors will contact you within 1 working day.<br /><br />
                    <span style="font-weight:bold">We do not share your details, also we do not spam!</span>
                    <br /><br />
                    We hate PopUps as much as you do, but don't let this discourage you from taking a look at our website.<br />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="columns five">
                <input type="hidden" name="intLeadGroupID" value="46320" />
                <input type="hidden" name="strSource" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="strMedium" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="strTerm" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="intSiteID" value="15334" />
                <input type="hidden" name="intReferrerBuyerID" value="0" />
                <input type="hidden" name="strAPISuccessURL" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="strAPIFailURL" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="strAPISuccessURL" value="http://www.office-training-courses.co.uk/thankyou" />
                <input type="hidden" name="strAPIFailURL" value="http://www.office-training-courses.co.uk/sorry" />
                <input type="hidden" name="strLeadData2" value="Lead is from ECDL contact page" />
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="strLeadFirstName" id="strLeadFirstName" placeholder="First Name *" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="strLeadLastName" id="strLeadLastName" placeholder="Last Name *" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="strLeadPhone1" id="strLeadPhone1" placeholder="Phone *" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="email" name="strLeadEmail" id="strLeadEmail" placeholder="Email *" />
                </div>
                <textarea placeholder="Leave comment here..." id="strLeadData3" name="strLeadData3"></textarea>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" class="formButton" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- Popup contents is until here--><a class="popup-close" href="#popup">X</a>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfCQggTAAAAAFQLaPfR-RTrwXnaIetV1-hD6rMe"></div>
        <!--<div class="formImg"></div>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a cookie? Just use webstorage

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: Could you explain this? i basically want to have the effect of a jquery popup form where it will only popup once for the user and not again until they clear there cache

Comment: I am open to using jquery yes

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/DOM/Storage

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this into my code... My javascript / jquery isnt too great and i have never heard of this webstorage before

Comment: That blue text in my comment is a link. If you click on it (you do this with your mouse) it opens a new page on the internet contaniing information.

Comment: yes but if i have no idea on how to implement this into my work then what use it reading this... I have clicked on the link but still do not understand the concept of this method

Comment: I doubt SO is the place for you, because you seem to be needing hand holding and somebody to walk you through every step in the process instead of you having a specific question where a specific answer will suffice.

Comment: Just because others are not as capable as yourself it doesnt mean that they should not be helped... I have tried many different solutions but not been able to get this to work.  I have created modal popups before using stuff like colorbox.js but i am trying to create my own which is something i have never done before and my javascript/jquery knowledge isnt AMAZING.  

So there is no need to include a comment such as yours if you didnt want to help then you should remove yourself from this thread.

Comment: Thanks to the answer below and the help of a nice person i have managed to fix my problem! 

"We are all human" 

Think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the browser localStorage for this. Just like:

First check on page load

```
var isfirst= localStorage.getItem('status');
if(isfirst==null)
{
   localStorage.setItem('status', 1);
   // SHow popup here
}
```

Complete HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0020)http://bilmen.co.uk/ -->
<html lang="en" class="no-js"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://bilmen.co.uk/images/favicon.ico">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PopUp Test</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="./PopUp Test_files/css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bilmen.co.uk/css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link href="http://bilmen.co.uk/css/skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://bilmen.co.uk/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://bilmen.co.uk/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="http://bilmen.co.uk/css/popupForm.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
    #popup{display:none;}

    </style>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="./PopUp Test_files/cb=gapi.loaded_0" async=""></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="./PopUp Test_files/recaptcha__en_gb.js"></script><script src="./PopUp Test_files/api.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var isfirst = localStorage.getItem('status');
            if (isfirst == null) {
                localStorage.setItem('status', 1);
                // SHow popup here
                $('#popup').show();
            }
        });

    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="./PopUp Test_files/api(1).js" gapi_processed="true"></script></head>
<body>

    <div class="popup-wrapper" id="popup">
        <div class="popup-container">
            <!-- Popup Contents, just modify with your own -->
            <form id="alreadyVisited" class="form-style1" method="post" action="http://robust.flg360.co.uk/api/APIHTTPPost.php">
                <div class="formLogo"></div>
                <h2>Enquire Now for a Free Information Pack</h2>
                <div class="columns six">
                    <p>
                        This form is simply here to speed up the process enter your details and one of our friendly &amp; professional
                        course advisors will contact you within 1 working day.<br><br>
                        <span style="font-weight:bold">We do not share your details, also we do not spam!</span>
                        <br><br>
                        We hate PopUps as much as you do, but don't let this discourage you from taking a look at our website.<br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="columns five">
                    <input type="hidden" name="intLeadGroupID" value="46320">
                    <input type="hidden" name="strSource" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="strMedium" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="strTerm" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="intSiteID" value="15334">
                    <input type="hidden" name="intReferrerBuyerID" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" name="strAPISuccessURL" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="strAPIFailURL" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="strAPISuccessURL" value="http://www.office-training-courses.co.uk/thankyou">
                    <input type="hidden" name="strAPIFailURL" value="http://www.office-training-courses.co.uk/sorry">
                    <input type="hidden" name="strLeadData2" value="Lead is from ECDL contact page">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="strLeadFirstName" id="strLeadFirstName" placeholder="First Name *">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="strLeadLastName" id="strLeadLastName" placeholder="Last Name *">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="strLeadPhone1" id="strLeadPhone1" placeholder="Phone *">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="email" name="strLeadEmail" id="strLeadEmail" placeholder="Email *">
                    </div>
                    <textarea placeholder="Leave comment here..." id="strLeadData3" name="strLeadData3"></textarea>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit!" class="formButton">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- Popup contents is until here--><a class="popup-close" href="http://bilmen.co.uk/#popup">X</a>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfCQggTAAAAAFQLaPfR-RTrwXnaIetV1-hD6rMe"><div><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="304" title="recaptcha widget" role="presentation" height="78" id="I0_1434107014820" name="I0_1434107014820" src="./PopUp Test_files/anchor.html"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea></div></div>
            <!--<div class="formImg"></div>-->
        </div>
    </div>







</body></html>
```

Comment: `localStorage` will hold value forever unless you delete it manually!! What happens is when the user visits next time after a couple of days then this will be true and no popup will be shown

Comment: `i basically want to have the effect of a jquery popup form where it will only popup once for the user and not again until they clear there cache` , user wants until cache is cleared pop-up should not come again. ** from comment in question'

Comment: Yes, it need to delete manully or it will delete with browser data.

Comment: Hey thanks for this quick response... I would really hope this works how do i link my form the this snippet of code? where it says ('status') do i put my forms id??? #popupForm

Comment: Anything you want instead of status, its the name of localstorage. you can use any friendly name  as per you.

Comment: Where the commented area is... do i have to put my popup code there???

Comment: Yes, you need to add your popup code

Comment: I am yet to get it to work :/

Comment: I am unsure on how this code interacts  with my form when they are not even linked...

Comment: you can use document.ready function and use the code inside this.

Comment: I am struggling to get this to work :/ i am sure that this is the correct method but i am unable to implement this to the code could you view the source at: http://bilmen.co.uk/

And let me know if it is correct?

Comment: You need to add firstly jquery file.

Comment: jquery file path: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: I have added complete html code in my edited answer.

Comment: This has not worked for me either... I have copied what you have done and put it in my code... But all it has done is hide the popup all together because of the:

#popup{
           display:none;
}

Comment: Plz update your code on bilmen.co.uk i will check it

Comment: FINALLY !!! I have done it with your help sehta umesh ! Thank you so much please see the code at bilmen.co.uk

Comment: Site also looking nice.

Comment: Hello , one more thing, i have checked your site. you are using already   <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script> so you not need to add again script as <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 window.onload = openForm;
function openForm(){
if(localStorage.getItem("alreadyVisited")){
return;
}else{
localStorage.setItem("alreadyVisited",true);
//open Pop-up

}
}
```